# Combine angular and grails

Tags: angular, grails

I followed [this tutorial](https://grails-profiles.github.io/angular/latest/guide/) to combine the default grails project generated with an angular profile into a single build. I now have access to the angular index.html from the grails server (`./gradlew bootRun)`. However how can I access other URLs on the server ? If I try to click on a link to /newPage, I have a `<router-outlet>` tag in my angular application which is supposed to update the DOM, but instead, the /newPage is handled by the grails UrlMappings, and thus results in a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are using  `routerLink` directives like:

```
 <a routerLink="/newPage" >
```

You can find out more informations [here.](https://angular.io/guide/router)